# fprintf prints random string letters (i.e. K or á) between numbers

Tags: matlab

I am having a trouble with `fprintf` and I would so much appreaciate if you could help me:
In the programme on which I am working now, I am tracking the mouse position when the mouse is clicked using `get(gca, ‘currentpoint’)` and then I save the final position using `fprintf`. Everything works smoothly when I do not define a particular axis position in the figure window; however when I use `set(gca, ‘visible’, ‘off’, ‘position’, [])` command to define a particular axis position, `fprintf` sometimes writes down a string, either `K` or `á`, on the text file, which then gives the obvious error for `dlmread` when the file is tried to be read. I wonder what might be the cause of those strings on the text file.

Here's the code:

```
mouse = get(gca, 'currentpoint');
A = mouse(1, 1);
B = mouse(1, 2);
save x_center4.txt A -ascii;
save y_center4.txt B -ascii;
A = load('C:\MATLAB6p5\work\x_center4.txt');
B = load('C:\MATLAB6p5\work\y_center4.txt');
fid = fopen('grand_xcenter4.txt', 'a');
fid2 = fopen('grand_ycenter4.txt', 'a');
fprintf(fid, '%s %d\n', A);
fprintf(fid2, '%s %d\n', B);
fclose(fid);
fclose(fid2);
```

Comment: Without any code it's hard to say anything where's the bug. Please add the relevant parts of your code that are needed to reproduce the error.

Comment: Thanks but my code is pretty long and complicated (and needs some jpeg files already saved in the directory to run) and everything's dependent on everything so I do not know how can I simplify to put it here for a quick look. I would so much appreaciate some general comments on why fprintf might be writing random strings on the number file, though, if possible?

Comment: Could you at least post the fprintf calls in question, showing precisely which format strings you're using etc.?

Comment: Thanks. Here it is:

`mouse = get(gca,'currentpoint');
A=mouse(1,1);
B=mouse(1,2);
save x_center4.txt A -ascii; 
save y_center4.txt B -ascii;
A=load('C:\MATLAB6p5\work\x_center4.txt');
B=load('C:\MATLAB6p5\work\y_center4.txt');
fid=fopen('grand_xcenter4.txt','a'); fid2=fopen('grand_ycenter4.txt', 'a');
fprintf(fid,'%s %d\n',A); fprintf(fid2,'%s %d\n',B); 
fclose(fid); fclose(fid2);`

Comment: @user1365673: don't post code in comments.  If you want help from SO, make it easy for us to help you.  Edit your question and include your code there.  If you don't have the rep to edit your question then delete it and post anew.

Comment: Pasted code from comment into the question. @user1365673 next time please embed the code in the question itself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fprintf(fid, '%s %d\n', A);
fprintf(fid2, '%s %d\n', B);
```

You are providing only 1 argument after the format string, when the format string specifies two arguments: a string (`%s`) and a base 10 signed integer (`%d`)?

This is most likely the cause of the strange characters you are reporting.  It may help to know what the type and value of `A` and `B` are before the `fprintf` calls.

I've been looking for official documentation of what constitutes "Undefined Behavior" in MATLAB, but have yet to find a good source.  However, failing to provide the right number and type of arguments that the string specifies almost certainly qualifies.

Comment: @EitanT The reason I wasn't more concrete in my wording is because I'm having a hard time finding a formal definition of "Undefined behavior" in MATLAB - it seems that this probably fits the definition, but I can't seem to find official documentation.

Comment: Hi, in fact, this was the exact problem! It works perfectly fine now! Thank you very much! The syntax I am using now:
`fprintf(fid, '%6.4f', A);`
It is stange, though, the previous syntax - being obviously wrong - gave me error only when I set the axis position to something else than the default.
The current syntax works for either case. You saved my day!